# How to consider another column in where condition if one column is null

Tags: sql-server

I have table like below,

```
Order_id      Created_Date       Approved_Date
_______________________________________________
1              2016-08-01         2016-08-05
2              2016-07-01         2016-07-04
3              2016-06-01         NULL


Select * from table1 where Approved_date between '2016-05-01' and '2016-08-31'
```

If the Approved_date is NULL, it should consider Created_date dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from table1 
where coalesce(Approved_date, Created_Date) between '2016-05-01' and '2016-08-31'
```

or to keep making use of indexes

```
Select * from table1 
where 
(
   Approved_date is not null 
   and Approved_date between '2016-05-01' and  '2016-08-31'
)
or 
(
   Approved_date is null 
   and Created_Date between '2016-05-01' and  '2016-08-31'
)
```

Comment: You've mixed up the dates in your second query. (And I doubt that SQL Server would use an index for that query, but it may be worth a try. A pity that SQL Server doesn't support function indexes where you would simply index `coalesce(approved_date,created_date)`.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT t1.Order_id,
       t1.Created_Date,
       COALESCE(t1.Approved_Date, t1.Created_Date)
FROM table1 t1
WHERE Approved_date BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-08-31'
```

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms190349.aspx):

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

In other words, in the above query `Approved_Date` will be used if it be not `NULL`, otherwise it was fallback to the `Created_Date`.